# how can an embedded ajax request in html be detected with python?

Tags: python, html, ajax, request, response

how can an embedded ajax request in html be detected with python?

when I searched for this on google, the only answers that came up explain how to detect that a response is AJAX. That isn't the problem though. I need to know if the HTML response is making subsequent AJAX requests (that a programmed HTML request won't get.) I know this is possible because an HTML response with embedded AJAX requests returns a different source code in the Python interactive session compared to viewing page source in the browser.

What consistent pattern should be in an HTML response to say to Python, "HTML response is making subsequent AJAX requests = True".

Comment: If subsequent AJAX calls are being made, then this could be judged by the JS part of the code. See if it makes any request, either in raw JS or Jquery. Could you please elaborate what your program is trying to do, so we could help better.

Comment: I'm trying to make a scraper that is smart enough to realize that an Ajax request was sent by the HTML document. So that it knows that the urllib2 HTML response was no good, and to either render the page in PyQT or with PhantomJS. What should I specifically look for in the JS part of the code?